# Error when running Apache Nutch application from JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, nutch

I use `onejar-maven-plugin` to package Apache Nutch application.

Application works fine when I run it from IDE.

`onejar-maven-plugin` packages fine, include all dependent JARs, without any errors, but when I try to launch this JAR from command line I get an exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \my-jar-0.0.1-S NAPSHOT.one-jar.jar
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:
>   1243)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java
>   :1107)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1053
>   )
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:420)
>           at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchConfiguration.setUUID(NutchConfiguration.j
>   ava:41)
>           at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchConfiguration.create(NutchConfiguration.ja
>   va:73)

On this lines:

```
Properties p = new Properties();    
conf = NutchConfiguration.create(false, p); // here exception
```

Where can be problem?

Comment: where you write "// here exception" a stacktrace would probably be pretty helpful....

Answer (score 0):

Onejar is quite complicate to use as Hadoop job. Try [shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/); it becomes an ugly package but much probably will work.
Packing Nutch with your applications is quite complicated because of the dependencies. In Hadoop one possibility is put them in `/lib` inside your `.jar`, but you will face more problems for sure.